# Jpanel and Jframe showing up separately when run

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, awt

I want to add a bunch of buttons in a vertical format to a JPanel which is then added to a container to a JFrame, when I run the program, the JPanel shows up as a separate window as the JFrame. There is no error messages. Code is below

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class MyFrame extends JFrame implements MouseMotionListener, ActionListener{
    private JFrame f;
    private JPanel p;

    private Color currentColor;

    JButton red, yellow, white, pink, orange, magenta, light_gray, green, gray, dark_gray, cyan, blue, black; 


    public MyFrame() {
        f=new JFrame("Emoji Editor");
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setSize(1200,1200);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        gui();
    }

    private void gui() {//set up the color selection button to the right

        //initializing the buttons

        red = new JButton("red");
        red.setBackground(Color.red);
        red.addActionListener(this);

        yellow = new JButton("yellow");
        yellow.setBackground(Color.yellow);
        yellow.addActionListener(this);

        white = new JButton("white");
        white.setBackground(Color.white);
        white.addActionListener(this);

        pink = new JButton("pink");
        pink.setBackground(Color.pink);
        pink.addActionListener(this);

        orange = new JButton("orange");
        orange.setBackground(Color.orange);
        orange.addActionListener(this);

        magenta = new JButton("magenta");
        magenta.setBackground(Color.magenta);
        magenta.addActionListener(this);

        light_gray = new JButton("light_gray");
        light_gray.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
        light_gray.addActionListener(this);

        green = new JButton("green");
        green.setBackground(Color.green);
        green.addActionListener(this);

        gray = new JButton("gray");
        gray.setBackground(Color.gray);
        gray.addActionListener(this);

        dark_gray = new JButton("dark_gray");
        dark_gray.setBackground(Color.darkGray);
        dark_gray.addActionListener(this);

        cyan = new JButton("cyan");
        cyan.setBackground(Color.cyan);
        cyan.addActionListener(this);

        blue = new JButton("blue");
        blue.setBackground(Color.blue);
        blue.addActionListener(this);

        black = new JButton("black");
        black.setBackground(Color.black);
        black.addActionListener(this);
        //initializing the Jpanel

        JPanel colorButtonPanel=new JPanel();
        colorButtonPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(12,1));//row,column
        colorButtonPanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        //add buttons to Jpanel
        colorButtonPanel.add(black);
        colorButtonPanel.add(cyan);
        colorButtonPanel.add(dark_gray);
        colorButtonPanel.add(gray);
        colorButtonPanel.add(green);
        colorButtonPanel.add(light_gray);
        colorButtonPanel.add(magenta);
        colorButtonPanel.add(orange);
        colorButtonPanel.add(pink);
        colorButtonPanel.add(white);
        colorButtonPanel.add(yellow);
        colorButtonPanel.add(red);

        //add JPanel to Container which I assumed is referring to the JFrame???
        Container pane = this.getContentPane();
        pane.setLayout(new BorderLayout()); 
        pane.add(colorButtonPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);
        setVisible (true);

    }

    //action stuff
}
```

and the main is

```
public class main {
    public static void main (String[] args) {       
        MyFrame p = new MyFrame();
    }
}
```

[![and a screenshot of the outcome
][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1pVIb.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1pVIb.png)

Any help would be very appreciated

Comment: `f.setVisible(true);` this should be last.

Comment: You're creating two instances of `JFrame` ... so, I'm already confused

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/) (like seen in my answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original code was opening two frames. Both of them needed a call to `pack()`.

This code uses the frame that was extended, for simplicity, though it is better to use an instance of a standard frame.

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MyFrame extends JFrame {

    JButton red, yellow, white, pink, orange, magenta, light_gray, green, gray, dark_gray, cyan, blue, black;

    public MyFrame() {
        /* all this is pointless
         f = new JFrame("Emoji Editor");
         f.setVisible(true);
         f.setSize(1200, 1200);
         f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
         */

        gui();
    }

    private void gui() {//set up the color selection button to the right
        //initializing the buttons
        red = new JButton("red");
        red.setBackground(Color.red);

        yellow = new JButton("yellow");
        yellow.setBackground(Color.yellow);

        white = new JButton("white");
        white.setBackground(Color.white);

        pink = new JButton("pink");
        pink.setBackground(Color.pink);

        orange = new JButton("orange");
        orange.setBackground(Color.orange);

        magenta = new JButton("magenta");
        magenta.setBackground(Color.magenta);

        light_gray = new JButton("light_gray");
        light_gray.setBackground(Color.lightGray);

        green = new JButton("green");
        green.setBackground(Color.green);

        gray = new JButton("gray");
        gray.setBackground(Color.gray);

        dark_gray = new JButton("dark_gray");
        dark_gray.setBackground(Color.darkGray);

        cyan = new JButton("cyan");
        cyan.setBackground(Color.cyan);

        blue = new JButton("blue");
        blue.setBackground(Color.blue);

        black = new JButton("black");
        black.setBackground(Color.black);
        //initializing the Jpanel

        JPanel colorButtonPanel = new JPanel();
        colorButtonPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(12, 1));//row,column
        colorButtonPanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        //add buttons to Jpanel
        colorButtonPanel.add(black);
        colorButtonPanel.add(cyan);
        colorButtonPanel.add(dark_gray);
        colorButtonPanel.add(gray);
        colorButtonPanel.add(green);
        colorButtonPanel.add(light_gray);
        colorButtonPanel.add(magenta);
        colorButtonPanel.add(orange);
        colorButtonPanel.add(pink);
        colorButtonPanel.add(white);
        colorButtonPanel.add(yellow);
        colorButtonPanel.add(red);

        //add JPanel to Container which I assumed is referring to the JFrame???
        Container pane = this.getContentPane();
        pane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        pane.add(colorButtonPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyFrame p = new MyFrame();
    }
}
```

Comment: interesting, where should i initialize the JFrame then?